# REM as VW responsive css site

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, viewport-units

Im making something like this: http://codepen.io/axlpl/pen/vEOyqL
but when you resizing browser sometimes right site is under left not in one line, can any one help me to fix this issue? in Sass function vw its function to get procent, first arg "$size" its project size, here I got 1200px, second arg its "$target" its element size 
in example in project size 1200px we got element wrapper with 400px size;

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left--green"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="block--red"></div>
        <div class="block--black"></div>
        <div class="block--blue"></div>
        <div class="block--yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
@function vw($size, $target) {
    $vw: $size / 100;
    @return ($target / $vw) * 1rem;
}


.wrapper {
    width: vw(1200, 400);
    height: vw(1200, 200);
    float: left;
}

.left,
.right {
    width: vw(1200, 200);
    height: vw(1200, 200);
    float: left;
    display: block;

    &--green {
        @extend .right;
        background: green;
    }
}

.block {
    height: vw(1200, 100);
    width: vw(1200, 100);
    float: left;

    &--red {
        @extend .block;
        background: red;
    }

    &--blue {
        @extend .block;
        background: blue;
    }

    &--yellow {
        @extend .block;
        background: yellow;
    }

    &--black {
        @extend .block;
        background: black;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}

function updateVw(){
    var vw = (viewport().width/100);
    if(vw % 2) {
      console.log('tak');
    } else {
      console.log('nie');
    }
    jQuery('html').css({
        'font-size' : vw + 'px'
    });
}

updateVw();

jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    updateVw();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a rounding problem. The width of your inner div elements is `16.666667%` and for some breakpoints they exceed the width of the parent (which is `33.333333%`); when this happens, as you've observed, the second div is shifted under the first one

As a workaround you may simply define the width of the inner `div`s like so

```
.left--green, right {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emNgmb